# Where's the best place to find lumps of earth?

Tags: glitch-2011

I need lots of earth, but it's so rare I'm having a hard time finding it. Is there a region in which it is more commonplace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best resource for locating resources in the game is [Zog's Glitchy Tools](http://zoggish.appspot.com/locations).  In addition to telling you where all the Dirt Piles are, it will also suggest the closest location to you to find some using the Glitch API.

[Kajuu](http://zoggish.appspot.com/hubs/85), for instance, is absolutely *buried* in dirt.

Answer (score -2):

I can't remember it exactly but the cave areas near the top right of the starting map and in the next map over in that area I think really caves have the most so wonder the caves also you can look up what is in an area ahead of time on the encyclopedia.

Comment: This answer is useless. There's more than a dozen starting locations in the game, and many more 'caves' of various sizes in the game. The 'caves' in the upper right corners are mining areas, for rocks not dirt